# Recursively calling a method for about (2^60)+ times in python

Tags: python

I am having a case where a method should be called recursively for about (2^60) or more number of times

I made successfully up to 2^9 then is caused "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" is there any way to do this

I am trying to change it to a Iterative method

I am using Python Language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum recursion depth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because recursively callign it 2^60 is properly not the answer. There are most properly much more effecient ways to go about this

Comment: Add code that demonstrate problem.

Comment: The recursion depth can be overridden, but you're almost guaranteed to run into an OutOfMemory error or something similar after 2^60 calls.  You _probably_ want to reframe your approach to whatever you're attempting to solve.

Comment: Even without the stack size constraints, even *looping* to `2**60` without doing any work in the loop would take centuries. This is never going to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your function to iterate instead of recurse.
Example:

```
def recursionSum(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    return n + recursionSum(n-1)

def iterativeSum(n):
    sum = 0
    while(n>0):
        sum += n
        n = n-1 # update parameter and loop again
    return sum
```

You need to do this because even if your function is tail recursive(doesnt maintain a call frame on the stack after it finishes) python doesnt optimize it. So you cannot use long recursive calls in python. Refactor your code to iterate. Provide your code and I can guide you through the process.

EDIT: here is something you can read on tail recursion ([What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion))

Comment: My function is fairly complex to solve by iteration. It is a Bellman equation. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You can rewrite it as iteration, trust me. Or you can use a language that does support tail recursion. However someone made a good point. 2^60+ is huge... it will not stop in your life time. Can you improve the algorithm so it doesn't recurse as much?

Comment: Well, I'm not the one who asked the question. But I've tried to convert my function into iteration, without success. I don't know if someone can help me convert it to iteration. Using another language will require conversion of python objects and all that.

Comment: You can post a new question and hopefully someone can help you with the transformation of the function and also maybe some code optimizations. This is a good example where the language choice matters.  Sorry for not checking your name initially.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you looking at something involving Bellman Equations, I suggest that you look for implementations regarding that.

A quick Google search found [this example on GitHub by rncarpio](https://github.com/rncarpio/bellman/blob/master/bellman.py).

I haven't taken a in-depth look at it, but it may give you something to either use, or base your own implementation off of.

Answer (score 0):

[Python Docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

> ```
> sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)
> ```
>
> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> **The highest possible limit is platform-dependent.** A user may need to set the limit higher when she has a program that requires deep recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash. (emphasis mine)

So put `sys.setrecursionlimit(n)` or however large you need it before your function. As said in the documentation, your platform may set a limit on `n`. However `2**60` is not attainable in the python interpreter. I therfore suggest you implement your function iteratively instead of recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(n)
```

where `n` is a large number. This is a limit set by the interpreter, another limit is set by the OS. Therefore for large `n` you will see a different error message. 2^60 recursion calls are definitely not attainable.